# Проблемы при наложении одного изображения на другое

Tags: python, python-3.x, pillow

У меня возникли проблемы при наложении одного изображения на другое. Мне нужно убрать нижние иконки. Для этого я беру часть с центра и вставляю ее на место иконок. Я написал код, но возникает ошибка. Вот сама [картинка](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2dG8.jpg). Но у меня возникает ошибка: `ValueError: bad transparency mask`.

```py
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open("screen.jpg")
foundation = image.crop((0, 284, 1080, 2204))
bottom = image.crop((400, 2024, 600, 2264))
foundation.paste(bottom, (0, 2024),  bottom)
foundation.save("screenNew.jpg")
```

Comment: ну так не задавайте маску прозрачности. зачем у вас второй раз записано `bottom` в foundation.paste ?

Comment: В Google Colab никакой ошибки нет, кстати.